# Get the superior of the employee. Then get again the superior of the superior of the employee. And so on

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have an employees table in which it has a column Employee_ID and SuperiorID. And I want to get all the hierarchy superiors of a specific employee. such as the superiors of Employee_ID-1000000 are 1000001,1000002,1000003,1000004, and 1000005

```
+--------------------------+
| Employee_ID | SuperiorID |
+--------------------------+
|   1000000   |    1000001 |
|   1000001   |    1000002 |
|   1000002   |    1000003 |
|   1000003   |    1000004 |
|   1000004   |    1000005 |
+--------------------------+
```

Employee_ID - 1000005 is the president of the company.

I have a query right now:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeNo AS INT = 1000000
SELECT Superior_ID from EmployeeTable WHERE Employee_ID  = @EmployeeNo
UNION
SELECT Superior_ID from EmployeeTable WHERE Employee_ID  = (select Superior_ID from EmployeeTable WHERE Employee_ID  = @EmployeeNo)
UNION
SELECT Superior_ID from EmpoyeeTable WHERE Employee_ID = ( SELECT Superior_ID from EmployeeTable WHERE Employee_ID  = (select Superior_ID from EmployeeTable WHERE Employee_ID  = @EmployeeNo))
```

Is there a better way on doing this one?

Thank You for your assistance.

Comment: Recursive CTE??

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need `recursive cte` :

```
DECLARE @EmployeeNo AS INT = 1000000;
with cte as (
  select Employee_ID, SuperiorID
  from EmployeeTable where Employee_ID  = @EmployeeNo
  union all 
  select e.Employee_ID, e.SuperiorID
  from cte join EmployeeTable e on cte.SuperiorID = e.Employee_ID
  where e.Employee_ID <> '1000005' --president
)
select * from cte;
```

Comment: sorry i did not include my query until it will reach the President as a superior.

Comment: @Rigel1121 , see updated asnwer , you need to add a condition to your recursive cte

Answer (score 0):

We can use a recursive hierarchical query here.  The strategy below is to build out the full hierarchy beginning with employee `1000000` going up the chain of command.  The recursion stops at employee `1000004`, whose superior does not have a further record.  In the recursive CTE below, I keep track of a counter, which is incremented with each step taken as with go up the hierarchy.  Then, we select only the highest ranking record using a `TOP` trick.

```sql
WITH cte (EmployeeID, SuperiorID, n) AS (
    SELECT Employee_ID, SuperiorID, 1
    FROM EmployeeTable
    WHERE Employee_ID = 1000000
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.Employee_ID, e.SuperiorID, n+1
    FROM cte t
    INNER JOIN EmployeeTable e
        ON t.SuperiorID = e.Employee_ID
)

SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM cte
ORDER BY n DESC;
```

### Demo

Comment: sorry i did not include my query until it will reach the President as a superior.

Comment: @Rigel1121 Not clear what you want here then.  Include the exact output you do want in your original question.  Most likely, I need a one-line change to my answer only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE     @EmployeeTable  TABLE   (EmployeeID int, SuperiorID int);
INSERT INTO @EmployeeTable
    VALUES  
            (1000000, 1000001)
        ,   (1000001, 1000002)
        ,   (1000002, 1000003)
        ,   (1000003, 1000004)
        ,   (1000004, 1000005)
;

DECLARE @EmployeeNo int =   1000004
    ,   @President  int =   1000005
;

WITH    Employee    AS
    (
        SELECT 
                EmployeeID  =   @EmployeeNo
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  EmployeeID =  S.SuperiorID
        FROM    Employee        E
        JOIN    @EmployeeTable  S ON S.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
    )

SELECT * FROM Employee
```